# How can I replace values in JSON in Redshift?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I have a column containing address information in JSON format. I want to replace street name and house number with '--'.

Here is what my column looks like:

```
{"1": {"house_no":1, "street_name":"street1"},  "2": {"house_no":2, "street_name":"street2"}}
```

So my column would look like this:

```
 {"1": {"house_no":"--", "street_name":"--"},  "2": {"house_no":"--", "street_name":"--"}}
```

In Redshift JSON is stored as VARCHAR column, so my assumption was that regexp function is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '"house_no":[^,}]+', '"house_no":"--"'), '"street_name":"[^"]+"', '"street_name":"--"')
```

In Redshift, this should replace all occurrences.  In most other databases, you need `1, 1, 'g'` for a global replace.